# Не понимаю/не знаю как сделать обработчик полей select

Tags: php, html

```
<form action=" ">
<p>
Какой ваш пол?
<select name="gender[]">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>

  <option value="F">Female</option>
  <input type='submit' name='formSubmit' />
</select>
</p>
</form>
<?php
$gender=$_POST['gender[]'];
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])&& is_array($gender))
{
foreach($gender as $key =>$value)
    {
        echo $key. $value. '<br>' or die();
    }
}
print_r($gender);
    ?>
```

не понимаю/не знаю как сделать обработчик полей select
с выводом что выбрали - натолкните подскажите

```
> $gender=$_POST['gender[]'];
> if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])&&
> is_array($gender)) { foreach($gender
> as $key =>$value)
>     {
>         echo $key. $value. '<br>' or die();
>     }
```

Comment: if (isset($_GET['gender']) &&
is_array($_GET['gender'])) { foreach($_GET['gender'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo $key. $value. '<br>' or die();
} } echo '<br>'; print_r($_GET['gender']);
я вот так вот учудил работает однако не понимаю как работает echo $key . $value и почему то при выводе перед print_r выводится единичка Как от нее избавиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе в $_POST['gender[]'] придет value выбранного элемента, т.е.:

```
$gender = $_POST['gender[]'];
if($gender=='M')
  echo "Select Male";
else if($gender=='F')
  echo "Select Female";
else
  echo "Not selected";
```

И да, лучше id задай просто gender.

Comment: if (isset($_GET['gender']) && is_array($_GET['gender']))
{
foreach($_GET['gender'] as $key=>$value)
{echo $key.  $value. '<br>' or die();
}}
 echo '<br>';
 print_r($_GET['gender']);

я вот так вот учудил работает однако не понимаю как работает echo $key . $value
и почему то при выводе перед prin_r выводится единичка
Как от нее избавиться?

Comment: решил вопрос.
спасибо

Comment: @городСпитПросыпае... и @Андрей Бакша,  спасибо вам, порадовали! ))  Сделал скрин вашей короткой переписки и, если опять загрущу, буду перечитывать в качестве лекарства ;)

Comment: @Deonis это как в игре Го - будучи 5к наблюдать за игрой 15к vs 18k